# Why is both "03 c8" and "01 c1" = add ecx, eax

Tags: assembly, x86

While using cheat engine I stumbled upon that both of these opcodes results in the same assembly code:

```
03C8 add ecx,eax
```

and

```
01C1 add ecx,eax
```

Why is this and is there any difference?

Comment: http://www.strchr.com/machine_code_redundancy

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22217436/encoding-adc-eax-ecx-2-different-ways-to-encode-arch-x86?rq=1

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Encoding ADC EAX, ECX - 2 different ways to encode? (arch x86)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22217436/encoding-adc-eax-ecx-2-different-ways-to-encode-arch-x86)

Answer (score 13, accepted):

The `01` form is `add r/m, r`, the `03` form is `add r, r/m`. Since both operands are registers, it can be encoded either way.